# recenter'ing a window that does not display current-buffer

Tags: window, scrolling

I am facing a recurring problem with `recenter` in Emacs. Sometimes, when I execute `recenter`, it doesn't work and I get the following message: `recenter'ing a window that does not display current-buffer.` And I notice that, when this happens, I cannot use the `consult` package to jump to the desired position, even though I am able to preview them.

This issue appears to be random, as I haven't been able to identify any specific set of steps to reproduce it. Can anyone offer any insights on what might be causing this problem?

Comment: See the thread at https://lists.gnu.org/r/emacs-devel/2014-06/msg00094.html for why this error checking was added to the implementation of `recenter`, although that does not at all explain why you get it when you call it interactively (if that is what you do). What happens if you toggle `debug-on-error` to `t` and try to reproduce it? If it happens and you get a backtrace, then add the backtrace to your question.

Comment: @NickD `C-h f` says it's an interactive function. I cannot get any backtrace.

Comment: If you don't see the problem when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file) then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Are you calling `recenter` from Lisp, or are you using `C-l`, which is bound to `recenter-top-bottom`? Provide a step-by-step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q`, to reproduce the problem, saying at each step what you see and what you expected to see instead.